# Java cyrillic encoding

Tags: java, character-encoding

I have input string - `UAH;"Ãîëüô 855229-7"`, it should be displayed like `UAH;"Гольф 855229-7"`, I'm trying to use `Cp1251` encoding, but get output `UAH;"????? 855229-7"`.

```
String cyrillic = row[0] + row[1];
String utf8String= new String(cyrillic.getBytes("Cp1251"), "UTF-8");
lbl1.setText(utf8String);
```

Comment: What your code does is: encode a string with Cp1251 encoding, and then decode it as if it is encoded with UTF-8. That obviously won't work, because you encoded it with Cp1251, not UTF-8. It's as if you have a book written in English that you want to translate to German, but you don't actually translate the book, you just tell the reader "Read this, it's in German" (while it's really in English).

Comment: What type is `lbl1`? If it's a Swing label, you just need to do `lbl1.setText(cyrillic);`. Assuming your font has cyrillic characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTF-8 has nothing to do with this.  All of your characters in `cyrillic` are being represented as single bytes.

Currently, those bytes are in the ISO 8859-1 encoding, also known as Latin-1, which is a subset of the Windows English code page, Cp1252.  So, you want to encode the string as Cp1252, then decode the resulting bytes as Cp1251:

```
String corrected8String = new String(cyrillic.getBytes("Cp1252"), "Cp1251");
```