# read symbols from file (cyrillic symbols)

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding

```
String text = new Scanner( url.openStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
```

I have this code, which read file from ftp
English symbols is reading good, but cyrillic like weird symbols
How can I fix it ?
In android studio encoding UTF-8

Comment: Do you use the correct encoding? [Java cyrillic encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48097025/java-cyrillic-encoding)

Comment: FTP won't tell you the correct character encoding (like HTTP could). So, you have to ask the file creator.